# Unity - Depth texture is too pixelated

Tags: unity, graphics

I am trying to combine two cameras together: Background camera, Foreground camera.

I created 3 cameras in my project, 2 for the background and foreground and one for the foreground depth.

I then created a simple shader that combine the first two cameras (they render to render texture as well as the foreground depth), the problem I am having is that because the depth buffer is too pixelated the result looks funny and you clearly see the lines around the foreground (players in my case).

I created a depth camera with these properties:

[image: Camera properties Unity]

Notice the `Output Texture`, I have set the Render texture to:

[image: Depth render texture properties]

This is the result depth texture (zoomed so you can see the pixels):

[image]

Any idea how I can create that effect maybe using something different then the depth buffer? or can I improve the depth quality? what can I do to reach a good final result?

Comment: What resolution is your game window?

Comment: @DMGregory HD, 1280x720, I tried up scaling it to 1920x1080 but the result is the same

Comment: So then in what sense is your depth texture more pixelated than your display render, if they're both drawing the same number of pixels? You may want to show us a side-by-side example to demonstrate this unambiguously.

Comment: @DMGregory I didn't say its more pixelated then my display render, I just want to create sort of a mask to show the player on the foreground, the problem is if the depth is so pixelated, when using my shader to combine the foreground and the background using the depth, you will noticeably see that the two textures are "stitched" together.

Comment: I don't follow in what sense the background is pixelated. It has exactly as many pixels as your display window, so each pixel is the same size. "Pixelated" means displaying something at an enlarged size, so you have a smaller number of larger pixels shown. Do you mean that you're looking for a way to fade the effect for partially transparent pixels, say along the edges of an antialiased sprite? Again, showing an example of that would make your question more clear.

Comment: @DMGregory Yeah I mean exactly that, sorry, make the foreground fit nicely (fade along the edges) on the background

Comment: It sounds then like this is the same problem as your previous question, and using the depth buffer this way is not a viable solution to that problem. I recommend deleting this question, and focus on making the requested edits to your previous question, so you can get high-quality answers there.